# What is gss_delegation_credential in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, kerberos

I'm trying to wrap my head around the kerberos protocol. So far, I understand what the purpose of KDC, TGT and SGT and I have some practice with kerberos utils (kinit, klist, etc). However, I do not understand how kerberos is implemented in practice.

For example, [keycloak documentation on kerberos](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#credential-delegation) mentions `gss_delegation_credential` which can be used to access other kerberos-secured services. As far as I understand, the process is the following:

1. Keycloak has it's own keytab file.
2. Keycloak fully handles the kerberos authentication process and stores all the credentials (i.e. TGTs and SGTs) inside aformentioned keytab file.
3. My server application receives a `gss_delegation_credential`, which can be used "to access other kerberos-secured services"

I read through kerberos section in keycloak documentation several times, but I cannot understand several things:

1. What exactly is `gss_delegation_credential`? Is it TGT, SGT or something completely different? Can I store it into a keytab file?
2. How should I use this credential to interact with other kerberos-secured services?

Answer (score 1):

> Keycloak has it's own keytab file.
>
> Keycloak fully handles the kerberos authentication process and stores all the credentials (i.e. TGTs and SGTs) inside aformentioned keytab file.

First of all, keytab files do not store tickets – they store keys (i.e. the *long-term* credentials), like the name says. The "key" is practically an equivalent of a password. Services use their keytab to decrypt and validate tickets received from users.

Keycloak, as a service that accepts Kerberos authentication (via HTTP SPNEGO), *doesn't* "fully" handle the whole Kerberos authentication process – i.e. it doesn't acquire a TGT on behalf of the user (that's done client-side), it doesn't even get to *see* the user's TGT at all.

All that it receives is a service ticket for "HTTP/sso.example.com", and that ticket is not stored anywhere at all; it's just validated and thrown away.

> What exactly is gss_delegation_credential? Is it TGT, SGT or something completely different? Can I store it into a keytab file?

From docs, this looks like what Microsoft AD would call "*unconstrained* delegation", or what kinit would call "forwarding". It's an exception to what I just said above – when unconstrained delegation is active for a service, the client *does* in fact deliberately include a copy of its TGT along with the service ticket, so that the server could store it somewhere (in a ticket cache) and do stuff on behalf of the client.

SSH is an easy way to see unconstrained delegation in action; if you have a non-Windows system that's set up with a "host/foo.example.com" principal (the standard "computer account") in /etc/krb5.keytab, you can `ssh -K` to it and you'll see the TGT from the client being copied to the server, showing up in `klist` there as well. (You would need to `kinit -f` first though, to mark the TGT as "forwardable".)

In the case of SSH, the delegated tickets are stored in a regular ticket cache (ccache). (Not in a keytab!) With Keycloak, since it's all handled by a different system, the tickets are instead stored as *part of the JWT* that Keycloak issues to the webapp you're logging in to, and that webapp needs to store them in a ticket cache.

Generally, unconstrained delegation is considered a bit of a security risk as it allows the service (in this case both Keycloak *and* the webapp) to fully assume your identity for as long as the ticket is valid, being able to do just as much as if it knew your password.

> How should I use this credential to interact with other kerberos-secured services?

I'm not entirely clear on what format the credentials are passed as in the JWT – they *might be* simply a base64 blob of a "ticket cache" file. So you generate a temporary file name, write the delegated credentials to it, and set it as your KRB5CCNAME before attempting to do the Kerberos operations.